# Song Plays in Background even Without Using Service

Tags: android, service, android-service

I am just clearing up my Android doubts. So lets talk about Services, we use services when we have to perform an operation in the background. Lets say Playing Music in the background? Thats one of the most popular reasons why people use Services.

But i just used Mediaplayer in my Mainactivity and i used `.start()` method in `onCreate` of my activity. I then minimized the app, but guess what....music still plays. I open the app again, and the music is still playing. I then remove the app from recent apps, basically destroying it and the music stops. Basically the app performs how it is supposed to. Works PERFECT!
Then why do we use services at all for these kind of tasks?

Is there any scenario this code might create a problem? Or is this creating some memory leak or something?

Answer (score 3):

When "minimized" the App continues to play music due to OS delay which allow an User to re-open the App without delay (due to a closure mistake?) because all remained in memory (even the Music) in the previous state.

But the memory is limited, and the CPU the same, so the OS could kill or freeze (using Doze) a background Activity in any moment without prompt User/Developer.

An Activity could be killed to claim Memory or freezed to save CPU cycles. In this situation only explicitely declared Background Services are allowed to run (however with some limitations and special-behaviours), so if you don't use Service your Music could stop in any moment in the future.

**PS**: even Background Service could be killed from OS, but this case is very-very rare and only on Extreme Low Memory situations.

Answer (score 0):

It will play as long as Android lets it live. It may stop at any moment, usually after 10-20 minutes.
Consider using Foreground Service to playback music. It will last until user kills it, and also provides notification bar with control over the playback.